# Group by months range between year in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Friends...I have here a sample data.

```
+-----------+-------+---------------+
| PRD       | AMT   |   Date        |
+-----------+-------+---------------+
|    1      | 100   |  14-JUL-03    |
|    1      | 100   |  16-JUN-04    |
|    1      | 200   |  18-JUL-04    |
|    1      | 200   |  14-MAY-05    |
|    2      | 100   |  20-JUL-05    |
|    2      | 100   |  14-OCT-05    |
|    2      | 100   |  26-APR-06    |
+-----------+-------+---------------+
```

I need to sum the amount field by grouping PRD & date between the range (01-JUL-year & 30-June-year+1). 
Example: For 2003-2004 year, need to compare the range between 01-July-2003 to 30-June-2004. Desired output should be like below:

```
PRD  |   Sum(AMT) |        year
 1   |    200     |      2003-2004
 1   |    400     |      2004-2005
 2   |    300     |      2005-2006
```

Any help in providing the query/logic would be much gladly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do the date -> year conversion in a derived table. GROUP BY it's result.

Answer (score 2):

The group criteria is prd and the second one is when you extract 6 months from the Date and truncates to year:

```
  SELECT prd, 
         SUM (amt), 
         TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS ("Date", -6), 'YYYY') || '-' || TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS ("Date", 6), 'YYYY') AS year
    FROM table_name
GROUP BY prd, TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS ("Date", -6), 'YYYY') || '-' || TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS ("Date", 6), 'YYYY')
ORDER BY 1, 3
```